# Android data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am developing this contacts app. So far i have generated a ListView witch has contact name and phone number. When you click on contact it starts new activity and shows contact name and phone number.

What I wanna do is that the ListView I have shows only contact names and when you click on contact in the list then the activity starts and you can see both name and number.

I thought maybe I can hide some of the information in ListView but I haven´t found anything good on that.

So does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - "When you click on contact it starts new activity and shows contact name and phone number." is awfully similar to "when you click on contact in the list then the activity starts and you can see both name and number."

Comment: okei sorry I was a bit unclear, What i ment was first when the program starts It shows list of contacts and I want it to show only the names of contacts. But right now it shows both name and phone number.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, query only contact name and id:

In your manifest you have to declare

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
> ```

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle){
       Uri uri                = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
       String[] projection    = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
       String sortOrder       = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        // Returns a new CursorLoader
        return new CursorLoader(
                    getActivity(),   // Parent activity context
                    uri,        // Table to query
                    projection,     // Projection to return
                    null,            // No selection clause
                    null,            // No selection arguments
                    sortOrder        // Sort by name
    );

}
```

Once you got the Cursor with contacts you have to pass that in a `CursorAdapter`

```
private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
};
private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
       android.R.id.text1
};


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
    mContactsList =
        (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contact_list_view);
    // Gets a CursorAdapter
    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.contact_list_item,
            null,
            FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
            0);
    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    // The list should now be shown.
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}
```